# What are good approaches for combining database-persisted and UI-only state in android with kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-viewmodel, kotlin-flow

I am writing a Todo App for android using Jetpack compose and Room as database solution.
For each Todo/Task I have some data that needs to be persisted in the database (e.g. text, due date, ...) and some that is UI-only (e.g. if the Task is currently expanded, showing more details).

The database/repository provides me with a flow of `Task` lists:

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName="task")
data class Task(
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int = 0,
  val text: String,
  val dueDate: LocalDate,
)

@Dao
interface TaskDao {
  // ...other methods
  @Query("SELECT * FROM task") fun getAllTasks(): Flow<List<Task>>
}

class TaskRepository(private val taskDao: TaskDao) {
  // ...other methods
  override fun getAllTasks() = taskDao.getAllTasks()
}
```

To display the tasks in the UI, I have a `TaskUiState` class. My screen-level ViewModel currently exposes a flow of `TaskUiState` lists:

```kotlin
data class TaskUiState(
  val id: Int,
  val text: String,
  val dueDate: LocalDate,
  val expanded: Boolean = false,
)

class MainScreenViewModel(
  private val taskRepository: TaskRepository,
) : ViewModel() {

  val taskList: StateFlow<List<TaskUiState>> =
    taskRepository
      .getAllTasks()
      .map { tasks -> tasks.map { TaskUiState(it.id, it.text, it.dueDate) } }
      .stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
        initialValue = emptyList()
      )
}
```

My problem now is that I cannot change if a task is expanded or not because I don't know how to properly store this information for each task and map it to the database entities.

I assumed this is a common problem, but couldn't find any info on it. What is a good and reasonably performant way to do this?
I have thought about storing a `Map<Int, Boolean>` from task ID to isExpanded. Then use this lookup when mapping `Task`s to `TaskUiState`s.
I would need to ensure that the `taskList` flow is updated when this  map changes, so I would probably need to use a `StateFlow<Map<Int, Boolean>>` and use the flow `combine` function. Is this approach viable? Note that I am not looking for a specific solution for the "expanded" state only (as this is only a minimal example) but for a more general approach of combining DB-persisted and UI-only state.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren’t making the expanded state part of the database? Are you only persisting that state for the current session of the app? That would be the easiest solution, but there are valid reasons you might want to do it differently.

Comment: The expanded state is nothing that needs to be stored permanently, it's just a visual thing. In addition, there is more state apart from expanded that shouldn't go into the database, I just tried to keep the question simple.

Comment: It's a good question, but I am not an expert on Compose. You ought to tag Compose, since this question is more related to that than to Room or ViewModels. You might also want to steer clear of the phrase "best practice" which makes people want to close your question for being opinion-based. The first part of your question could be solved a few different ways. The question in your update could be summarized as, how to you resolve the database being the source of truth for State, while being able to update TextInput elements quickly without waiting for the database write-read roundtrip?

Comment: This probably needs to be two separate questions because it has become too broad. The original question had nothing to do with Compose. I was going to answer it, but now with the second part, I cannot because it's two completely different subjects and I'm not an expert on Compose.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks for the constructive feedback! I will remove the second part again and make the edit part a separate question. Looking forward to your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally using `combine` is better approach but just use `Set` instead of `Map`

```
class MainScreenViewModel(
  private val taskRepository: TaskRepository,
) : ViewModel() {

    private val expandedTaskFlow: MutableStateFlow<MutableSet<Int>> = MutableStateFlow(mutableSetOf())
    
    val taskList: StateFlow<List<TaskUiState>> = 
            combine(taskRepository.getAllTasks(), expandedTaskFlow, ::taskUIState)
                    .stateIn(
                            scope = viewModelScope,
                            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
                            initialValue = emptyList()
                    )
    
    private fun taskUIState(tasks: List<Task>, expandedSet: MutableSet<Int>): List<TaskUiState> {
        return  tasks.map { TaskUiState(it.id, it.text, it.dueDate, it.id in expandedSet) } 
    }
    
    fun expand(taskId: Int) {
        expandedTaskFlow.value = expandedTaskFlow.value.apply { add(taskId) }
    }

    fun collpase(taskId: Int) {
        expandedTaskFlow.value = expandedTaskFlow.value.apply { remove(taskId) }
    }
}
```